# not giving perfect result

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, php-carbon

Time and date both are different fields but when I use this coding result is not perfect.

This is my code:

```
$challenges = Challenge::whereDate('c_date','>',Carbon::now())->get();
Challenge::whereTime('c_time','>',Carbon::now())->get();
```

Are there any problems in this code?

Comment: What do you mean by not perfect? Explain what you need more clearly compared with what you actually got.

Comment: Please add what you are expecting and what you get as a result.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly check the formate of date in c_date.Format should be ('Y-m-d').If your formate is okay then check your logic that what you really want?
I think your fault is your logic .You want to get those date where c_date is grater then now date.

```
$challenges = Challenge::whereDate('c_date','<',Carbon::now())->get();
```

Comment: Its working but i want to date and time both result..suppose today upcoming challenges at 5:00Pm, right now 4:00Pm, than its show me - @albus_severus